# code sign error

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I am am beginner.

I get a code signing error when I build and distribute my app for binary.
(Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain) i have created my first binary yesterday but today this error occurs...in simulator it is perfect but not in device and ditribution

Comment: its probably helpful if you provide us with the error message (you can edit your post).

Comment: in simulator ? just clean existing build and run freshly in simulator

Comment: (Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain)
i have created my first binary yesterday but today this error occurs...in simulator it is perfect but not in device and ditribution

Comment: Your provisioning profile contains the right device id? Please check device id in ur provisioning profile.

Comment: didnt getting rite.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the admin distribution certificate onto your mac .If you don't have distribution certificate you create other then that you can not do anything .  For create you have togo on to  this apple developer forum thought the admin a/c.Over there you will get this distribution certificate import in your mac and then try it to distribute this .On the apple developer forum you will get guide line for this how to create the certificate .If this work then select my answer .

Answer (score 0):

You should create the developer certificate in distribute tab after you create.
Provisioning also you should create distribute tab, please check these things you follow.